# Angularjs - ng-view inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-routing

I have a list of Products. For each one, I have buttons to show the details and comments about it inside this ng-view.

The user must to see in one pege the details about all products available, for example.

Here is the HTML list:

```
<div ng-controller="ProductsApp">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="product in products">
        <p>{{product.Name}}</p>
        <p>
            <a href="#/details/{{product.Id}}">Details</a>
            <a href="#/comments/{{product.Id}}">Comments</a>
        </p>
        <div ng-view="productView{{product.Id}}">
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then my routing:

```
angular
    .module('ProductsApp',[])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/details/:productId', {
                controller : DetailsCtrl, 
                templateUrl : 'Details.html',
                view: 'productView:productId'
            }).            
            when('/comments/:productId', {
                controller : CommentsCtrl, 
                templateUrl : 'Comments.html',
                view: 'productView:productId'
            }).
```

My controller:

```
function DetailsCtrl ($scope, $window, $http, DetailsList) {    
    var productId = $routeParams.productId;
    $scope.Details[productId] = DetailsList.get({'productId' : productId});
}
```

And finally the Details.html

```
<div>
    Name: {{Details[productId].Name}}
    Size: {{Details[productId].Size}}
    ...
</div>
```

Two questions about it:

1. Is it a right approach? Is there any other way to do it?
2. How can I get the productId for the actual ng-view?  Name: {{Details[**productId**].Name}}

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a way to make it work along the lines you're attempting, but I think it's a more complicated approach than you need. Angular really seems to expect one route at a time per controller, and working around that is likely to involve something hackish.

Instead, look at the tabs example on the front page at http://angularjs.org/. I'd handle this with a directive, though you could do without it. Something like this (off the cuff, so this may not work yet precisely as written):

```
<span ng-click='showDetails[$index] = true'>Details</span>
<span ng-click='showDetails[$index] = false'>Comments</span>

<div ng-show='showDetails[$index]'>Details here.</div>
<div ng-show='!showDetails[$index]'>Comments here.</div>
```

If you have behavior for the Details and Comments that require controllers, then I would go with directives. Write a directive for each (each with its own controller) and then the above just becomes something like:

```
<span ng-click='showDetails[$index] = true'>Details</span>
<span ng-click='showDetails[$index] = false'>Comments</span>

<details ng-show='showDetails[$index]'> data-id='{{product.id}}'></details>
<comments ng-show='!showDetails[$index]'> data-id='{{product.id}}'></comments>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try using directives approach. But if I let all the datas (products list with details and so on) in only one controller, can it become havy to the browser?

Comment: It's a question of what you want to optimize for, really. You didn't detail how 'products' is being pulled down or what its structure is. If you wanted, that could be just a list of names and ids, and the Details and Comments controllers could make their own API calls (via a $resource) to get the rest. It's the usual thing, though. If they do it at initial load, you haven't reduced the data volume. If they do it on-demand, there's the chance of rendering delay. Only you know which is more important for you.

Comment: McCrohan, can you help me in this question too?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16763463/angularjs-performance  Thanks!