# Angularjs performance

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a project that needs a good performance with a large number of records showed.

My data structure:

- SERVERS (+- 15 per page)

  - WEBSITES (+- 20 per server)

    - USERS logged in with your STATUS (+- 500 per website)

What is the best approach for my Objects and Controllers?

1. One Controller with one neasted object.

   ServerCtrl -> $scope.Server[0].Websites[0].Users
2. One Controller with three lists

   ServerCtrl -> $scope.Servers; $scope.Websites; $scope.Users
3. Three Controllers with three separated lists

   ServerCtrl -> $scope.Servers

   WebsiteCtrl -> $scope.Websites

   UserCtrl -> $scope.Users

Thanks!

Comment: At 150,000 objects total I'm guessing your performance issues will have much more to do with how you choose to retrieve you data rather than how you structure your controllers. That being said, in this situation ng-include (which lazy loads content) will definitely be your friend.

Comment: I agree 150K objects it's a challenge. You might find "ng-bindonce" handy for your views https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you are working with the data in the controller.

1. If you need access to all data for a specific server. Then you need
   data to the data inside the data. But it is a lot of data so maybe
   just read one server at the time or page?
2. I would instead only read one service at the time. But it all
   depends on what you want to do. Are the server, website and user not
   connected to each other then fine.
3. This approach works. Inside the server view you can have a website
   view with a controller and inside the website view you can have a
   user controller. It is a good way organize data. But the amount of
   data means that you probably need some sort of paging.

Answer (score 0):

The performance depends on how you manipulate the data. 
So you can use AngularJS Batarang (Chrome Extension) and check the number os watcher in your page and apply some methods to reduce this number and give more performance for your application.
Be careful with big lists and two way data binding, filters... They're villains of performance.